# Scraping em Python - ler pdf

Tags: python, pdf, scraping

Eu fiz um *scrapping* em Python que pega uma URL de um PDF qualquer, lê e retorna, porém em alguns PDFs estou tendo o problema de vir com uns caracteres assim:

> ".\nO \xc3\xb3rg\xc3\xa3o tamb\xc3\xa9m divulga
>   resultado\n\nGH\xc3\x80QLWLYR\x03GRV\x03FDQGLGDWRV\x03TXH\x03VH\x03GHFODUDUDP\x03FRP\x03GH\xc3\x80FLrQFLD\x03H\x03GRV\x03SHGLGRV\x03\nde
>   atendimento especial deferidos.\nO concurso visa o provimento\nefetivo
>   de 150 vagas para a classe\ninicial (Classe A) do cargo de delegado de
>   Pol\xc3\xadcia Civil, cujas vagas ser\xc3\xa3o\n\nprovidas conforme a
>   ordem de
>   clasVL\xc3\x80FDomR\x03H\x03D\x03QHFHVVLGDGH\x03GR\x03VHUYLoR\x11\nA"

Pelo que pude ver, isso acontece quando tem algum acento, coluna ou até traço no documento..

Também reparei que se tem imagem, me retorna caracteres estranhos! Alguém tem alguma solução ou ideia que possa me ajudar?

Comment: ja tentou `.unicode('utf-8') (utf8)` não me recordo bem...

Comment: Rapazes, obrigada pela ajuda.
Realmente existe o encode e decode que ajuda a resolver esses caracteres em UTF-8... Mas no texto ainda tem uma parcela de texto que isso não funciona, seria nesses trechos: "GHFODUD".

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra alternativa é usar [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) com *encoding* [*Latin 1*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) e [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) para decodificar para UTF-8. Veja um exemplo:

```
print ("\xc3\xb3".encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')) # ó
```

No teu caso, faça assim:

```
print (texto.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))
```

Onde `texto` é a variável que você quer aplicar o *encode/decode*.

Resultado:

> ```
> O órgão também divulga resultado
>
> GHÀQLWLYRGRVFDQGLGDWRVTXHVHGHFODUDUDPFRPGHÀFLrQFLDHGRVSHGLGRV
> de atendimento especial deferidos.
> O concurso visa o provimento
> efetivo de 150 vagas para a classe
> inicial (Classe A) do cargo de delegado de Polícia Civil, cujas vagas serão
>
> providas conforme a ordem de clasVLÀFDomRHDQHFHVVLGDGHGRVHUYLoR
> A
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Usando Python e [`pdfminer`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) ([`pdfminer3k`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k) para o Python 3), implementei a leitura de PDF através da seguinte classe:

```
import pdfminer
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import TagExtractor
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.utils import set_debug_logging
import io

class LeitorPdf():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.resource_manager = PDFResourceManager(caching=False)
        self.output_stream = io.StringIO()
        self.device = TextConverter(self.resource_manager, self.output_stream, laparams=None)

    def extrair_texto(self, file_name):
        fp = io.open(file_name, 'rb')
        process_pdf(self.resource_manager, self.device, fp, set(), maxpages=0, password='', caching=False, check_extractable=True)
        return self.output_stream.getvalue()
```

O PDF precisa ser salvo em algum lugar antes.

Uso:

```
texto = LeitorPdf().extrair_texto(nome_arquivo)
```